# Swift Extension For Generic type compiler error

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have created extension of Cache class for NSData generic type (https://github.com/aschuch/AwesomeCache)

First method works fine, but *setIntegerValue* show compiler error:
"Cannot invoke 'setObject' with an argument list of type '(NSData, forKey: String, expires: CacheExpiry)'" at line: *self.setObject(data, forKey: forKey, expires: expires)*

```
extension Cache where T: NSData {
    func integerForKey(key: String) -> Int? {
        if let data = self.objectForKey(key), string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding), intValue = Int(string) {
            return intValue
        }
        return nil
    }

    func setIntegerValue(integerValue: Int, forKey: String, expires: CacheExpiry = .Never) {
        let stringValue = String(integerValue)
        if let data = stringValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            self.setObject(data, forKey: forKey, expires: expires)
        }
    }
}
```

I have created test without extension which works perfectly:

```
let cache = try! Cache<NSData>(name: "MyCache")
let string = "foo"
if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    cache.setObject(data, forKey: "bar")
}
```

So, I don't understand what was happen? Could anybody tell me - what was wrong?

Comment: `extension Cache where T: NSData` — I thought Swift allows protocols only in `extension/where` type constraints. It won't even work with `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `data` is an NSData, but `setObject` takes a T as its first parameter. Not an NSData.

It's true that you have defined this extension for `T:NSData` but that doesn't matter to Swift.

Comment: I suppose you could get it to compile by writing `setObject(data as! T ...` but I have no idea what would happen at runtime. :) Possibly the universe would explode.

Comment: func integerForKey(key: String) ... has code: if let data = self.objectForKey(key) - it does't return 'T' but NSDada, so what is the difference for Swift that method parameter should be T, but return type is NSData?